# Vuetify combobox - How to filter out and remove wrong entries while typing in vuetify's combobox

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to let the users to type and select the items from the combobox. But somehow, if we type anything random and press tab, the combobox is taking that as input and that behaviour is not desired in my case.

```
 <v-row class="ma-1">
        <v-combobox
          v-model="selectedProperties"
          :items="propertyItems"
          label="Properties"
          :menu-props="{ maxHeight: 195 }"
          multiple
          chips
          closable-chips
          max-height="4"
        ></v-combobox>
      </v-row>
```

Comment: so you want to press tab and dive into the items?

Comment: Yes, or if the input is invalid then maybe throw an inline validation

Comment: tab is for html tabindex. purpose is to switch between form elements.
in your case you either hack the behavior, hijack and add your custom behavior on pressing tab or use arrow-keys to dive into the items.

Comment: You should use v-autocomplete if you don't want to allow input that do not exist within the provided items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `v-autocomplete` component instead of `v-combobox`

https://v2.vuetifyjs.com/en/components/combobox/

> The v-combobox component is a v-autocomplete that allows the user to
> enter values that do not exist within the provided items. Created
> items will be returned as strings.